# Listing state sales in query even if they had no sales that month

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am requesting some assistance from you experts in writing a SQL Server query. I must produce two table each month for a report that summarizes the count and sum of sales in each state. For simplicity sakes, let’s say the sales table only has 4 columns: Order number, date, state, and total. Table one lists all sales ever made in each state and a running total. The second chart lists only that month’s sales in each state.

[image] 
[image]

I can write the first query easy enough. My problem is the second query. The second table must contain any state what we have previously had sales in it even if there were no sales this month (which would then have a 0 number of orders and 0 total sales.). The two tables also sit side by side in the report which would make it obvious if one of them was missing a state for the monthly sales table. The report will be automated which means I cannot just simply add in the missing values. In the actual production environment, we currently have orders from 29 states. Next month, we might receive an order in a new (or several new) state(s) which means I cannot hard-code the state name in a like statement. Likewise, I cannot show states in the first table that have never had a sale in it (a management rule). Can someone assist me in putting this query together? I just can’t seem to wrap my head around the syntax. I appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Comment: Please show your first query.  And sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you write two queries?  Just write one with five columns:

```
select state,
       count(*) as orders_total,
       sum(total) as sales_total,
       sum(case when date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2019-02-01'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as orders_201901,
       sum(case when date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2019-02-01'
                then total else 0
           end) as sales_201901
from t
group by state
order by state;
```

Comment: I am required to have two seperate tables, however, I don't have to use every column of the query in every table so this is certainly an option and would probably have a performance advantage then writing two seperate queries.